# How should I handle HATEOAS links and references in JSON?

Tags: json, rest, hateoas

I'm in the process of designing a REST api and to be as RESTful as it gets. I want to incorporate [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) into the json responses.

Adding URLs to related resources is easy enough, but there was some discussion over the structure to use for those links.

A LOT of articles I found use a structure borrowed from [ATOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(standard)) feeds:

```
"links": [ 
    {"rel": "self", "href":"http://example.org/entity/1"},
    {"rel": "friends", "href":"http://example.org/entity/1/friends"}, ... 
]
```

This raised some questions:

- **Why use an array as a container?** According to a javascript developer I know, access to the links would be easier with the links as properties of an object. For example:

  ```
  "self":    { "href":"http://example.org/entity/1" }, /* (facebook uses this) */  
  "friends": { "href":"http://example.org/entity/1/friends", "type": "..."}
  ```
- **Is there a common json structure** (beside adapting atom again) **to describe references in resource properties?** (for example the sender of a message).

  The reference should probably be resolved as a url again, but would it be bad to include the simple id as well? kind of like:

  ```
  "sender": { 
      "id": 12345,
      "href": "resource-uri"
  }
  ```

My way of thought is that while HATEOAS makes it so a client doesn't need a lot of knowledge to use an API, I'm kind of reluctant to remove the possibility to USE that knowledge (like accessing the profile picture by building the link client-side without looking up the user first).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I restarted this topic on the API-Craft google group and got some great responses.

The main advantages of the Array design are:

- multiple links for the same relationship
- multiple relationships for the same link without writing the link aggain
- the ability to order the links

The map of cause has better accessibility.

As far as structure goes there are a lot of possibilities:

- JSON-HAL:  http://blog.stateless.co/post/13296666138/json-linking-with-hal or also http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html
- JSON-LD: http://json-ld.org/ (optionally using [Hydra](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/) vocabulary)
- JSON-Schema: http://json-schema.org/ (theHyper Meta-Schema on the bottom of the page)
- Collection+JSON: http://amundsen.com/media-types/collection/

I guess i will go with HAL as it is the cleanest solution, the rest all look kind of... strange for json.

Comment: Ha! Looks like you answered your own question while I was composing a response. Thanks for the update!

Comment: When you say one of the advantages of Array design is multiple links for the same relationship, the above array in the original question is for different relationships in one array. So isn't that a little bit different style than what you originally asked about?

Comment: @ammianus - By having the relationship as an attribute of an individual link, you can have it's value be a list of relationships, which is not possible if the relationship is the key and the url the value. The same holds for the href.

Comment: HAL is easy and simple, but with JSON-LD you got much more options...

Answer (score 4):

As far as structure goes, you could try looking at HAL (http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) or JSON-LD: (http://json-ld.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I think its so that you can offer multiple links based on the http method.

e.g.

```
"links": [ 
    {"rel": "sender", "method":"post", "href":"http://example.org/entity/1"},
    {"rel": "sender", "method":"put", "href":"http://example.org/entity/1"}, ... 
]
```

maybe you could adapt that to your idea

```
"sender": { 
     "href":"http://example.org/entity/1",
     "methods": ["put","post"]
}
```