# HATEOAS Content-Type : Custom mime-type

Tags: rest, hateoas

I've been trying to implement a RESTFul architecture, but I've gotten thoroughly confused as to whether custom media-types are good or bad.

Currently my application conveys "links", using the Http Link: header. This is great, I use it with a title attribute, allowing the server to describe what on earth this 'action' actually is, especially when presented to a user.

Where I've gotten confused is whether I should specify a custom mime-type or not. For instance I have the concept of a user. It may be associated with the current resource. I'm going to make up an example and say I have an item on an auction. We may have a user "watching" it. So I would include the link

`<http://someuserrelation> rel="http://myapp/watching";title="Joe Blogg", methods="GET"`

In the header. If you had the ability to remove that user from watching you would get.

`<http://someuserrelation> rel="http://myapp/watching";title="Joe Blogg", methods="GET,DELETE"`

I'm pretty happy with this, if the client has the correct role he can remove the relationship. So I'm defining what to do with a relationship. The neat thing is say we call GET on that 'relation' resource, I redirect the client to the user resource.

What's confusing me is whether or not to use a custom mime-type. There's arguments both ways on the internet, and in my head in regards to this.

I've done a sample in which I call `HEAD` on an unknown url, and the server returns `Content-Type: application/vnd.myapp.user`. My client then decides whether it can understand this mime-type (it maintains mappings of resources it understands to views), and will either follow it, or explain that it's unable to figure out what is at the end of that link.

Is this bad?. I have to maintain special mime-types. What's particularly odd is I'm more than happy to use a standard `application/user` format, but can't find one specified anywhere.

I'm beginning to think I should be attempting to completely guess at rendering what in any HTTP response, almost to the point that maybe my RESTFul api should just be rendering html instead of attempting to do anything with json/xml.

I've tried searching (even Roy Fieldings blog), but can't find anything that describes how the client should deal with this sort of situation.

EDIT: the argument I have with including the custom type, is that it may not necessarily be a 'user' watching the item, it could be something with `application/vnd.myapp.group`. By getting the response a client knows the body has something different, and so change to a view that displays groups. But is this coupling of `mime-type` to view bad?.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, you definitely want to have a specific media-type for all representations. If you can find a standard one (html, jpeg, atom, etc.) use that, but if not, you should define one (or multiple ones).

The reason is: representations should be *self-contained*. That means your client gets a link from somewhere it should know what to do with it. How to display it, how to proceed from there, etc. For example a browser knows how to display text/html. You client should know how to display/handle application/vnd.company.user.

Also, I think you've got content negotiation backwards. You don't need to call HEAD to determine what representations the server supports. You can tell the server what your client supports in the GET/POST/etc requests using the "Accepts" header. Indeed this would be the standard way to do it. The server then responds with the 'best' representation it can give you for your accepted mime-types. You don't need more round-trips.

So, although the links you are providing *can* contain contextual information, usually given in the 'rel' attribute, like if the link points to a 'next page', 'previous page', 'subscribed user' or 'owner user', etc., the client can not assume any representation under those links. It knows it is semantically a 'user', so it can fill the 'Accepts' header with all supported representations for a user (application/vnd.company.user). If the representation only says text/xml, there is nothing the client can assume either of the content, or semantics of Links that it may receive.

In practice you can of course code any client to just assume what representations are under what links/urls, and you don't have to conform to REST all the time, but you do get a lot of benefits (described in Roy Fielding's paper) if you do.

Another minor point: The links do not need to contain which methods are available for a given resource, that's what OPTIONS is for. Admittedly, it is rarely implemented.

Comment: See the thing that is strange for me is that the client, and possibly the mime-type would almost have to specify all the possibly things that could be 'watching'. I gave the example about in future maybe a changing the resource that is behind 'watching', eg to a group. You said the client semantically knows it a user.. but should it?. Shouldn't it get the mime-type the server sends back and deal with it that way, rather than assuming its a `application/vnd.app.user`, what if its a different resource that also has that relation?.

Comment: You don't have to specify that the link points to a user, if you don't want to. But, how do you know that there is a link in the first place? Or what its 'relation' attribute means? The point is, that any semantics you want to assign the returned representation has to be through a mime-type. So you at least have to define, that there are potentially links to subscribers, and this can only be done through a mime-type. Otherwise the message is not self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to send HTML to serve hypermedia. There are many different hypermedia formats which are much easier to parse than HTML. https://sookocheff.com/post/api/on-choosing-a-hypermedia-format/ https://stackoverflow.com/a/13063069/607033

You don't have to use a domain specific MIME type, in my opinion it is better to use a domain specific vocabulary with a general hypermedia type e.g. microformats or schema.org with JSON-LD + Hydra or ATOM/XML + microdata / RDFa, etc... There are many alternatives depending on your taste. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdata_(HTML) http://microformats.org/ http://schema.org/ http://www.hydra-cg.com/

I am not sure whether adding the same relation to multiple methods is a good choice. Sending multiple links with different  in link headers with d if you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25416118/607033